# chain functions

Tags: java

I have two classes

**Class1:**

```
public class Class1 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Class2 classObject = new Class2();
            classObject.add(2, 3);
            classObject.print();
        }
    }
```

**And Class2:**

```
public class Class2 {

    public int add(int a, int b) {
        int n = a + b;
        return n;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(add(2,3));
    }
}
```

I want to  use the `print` method to print out what is being returned in the add method.The add method gets its information from the `classObject` as seen in `Class1`.

I know there are different ways to go about doing this, but i'm quite sure that there is a way to do it the way i want to, i just can't figure out how.

In `Class2` in the print method when i called the add method i put arbitrary numbers there. What i want to do is somehow bring the numbers from from `classObject.add(int,int)` and print the the returning integer `n`.

Comment: I don't know.. what is your question.

Comment: `int foo = classObject.add(2, 3); System.out.println(foo);` ?

Comment: Your classObject.add(2, 3); returns an int value.  to print it in class1 you would use System.out.println("returned value="+classObject.add(2,3));

Comment: How is it unclear what is being asked here?

Comment: You don't hold on to the result of your add method. You can either declare a result int at the class level of Class2 or you can make Class.print() take an integer and print out that parameter.

Comment: Yes, i know i can create an int in my Class2 to hold on my results and then print out that integer, but that woulnd't require my add class to be an int, my add class could just aswell have been a void.

Comment: In that case you can either call the `Class2.print()` method from your `Class2.add() `method or you can store the result of `Class2.add()` in a variable in your the main method like `int result = classObject.add(2, 3);` and then just print it like `System.out.println(result)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change the signature of the print method as below. Method like print are processing methods which needs the input which you can pass as method arguments.

```
public void print( int a) {
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Now you need to make a simple call like below.

```
classObject.print(classObject.add(2,3));
```

You should not be calling add method from inside the print method. As per the name it seams print is a general purpose method. You should pass input as method arguments and it should be responsible to print the input.

If you wish your print method to just print addition then You can pass the two numbers as input parameters to method print and also change the method name as below. You need to call the method add from inside the print (modified version). In this case you should hide the method add and make it private.

```
public void printTheAddition(int n, int m){
    System.out.println(add(n,m));
}
```

In this case just call printTheAddition method with two input arguments.

Comment: You're right, your method works very fine. But since i'm learning i want to make it slightly complicated on myself so i know the ins and outs of java programming.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing ut pass an object from class1 into a class2 parameter?

Comment: I would rather tell you to learn to make the complicated logic simple. Code should always be Simple to understand and easy to maintain.   I suggest you to read good OOPs principle. Ideally code should be testable, understandable, browable and easy to maintain. You can also search and learn about S.O.L.I.D principles.

Comment: You can see , I have edited my answer, may be this will help you but still I insist you to understand the things but implement them in the simplest way. Badly written code is Complex, but complex logics can look Simple if coded properly.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want to demonstrate is showing an object with state, maybe you mean something like this:

```
public class Class2 {
    int n;

    public void add(int a, int b) {
        n = a + b;
        return n;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

This way Object1 never knows the internals of Object2, and it's really a pretty good abstraction.